# In representation theory terminology: Branching rule vs decomposition?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In representation theory's terminology, what are the differences between

- Branching rule?
- Decomposition?

We can take any spin group as examples such as Spin(3) or Spin(8). Are Branching rule vs decomposition the same thing or different?

Comment: "Decomposition" sounds like a more general term which is used also for other things, even in representation theory. As in: Decomposition of a representation/module into irreducible/simple subrepresentations/submodules; also: Decomposition of a rep. into weight spaces etc. Of course the branching (how a rep. decomposes when viewed as a rep of a subgroup) is *also* a kind of decomposition, but I would think it bad if an author uses only that word and not the more specific "branching".

Comment: If you have a specific source in mind and are unsure if something called branching or decomposition in there is the same thing, you should point to the exact source.

Answer (score 4):

'Decomposition' means that you are given a module and want to write it as a sum of (probably indecomposable) modules, or possibly compute its composition factors. This could be a restricted module, or a tensor product, or anything else.

A branching rule on the other hand is a general description of how to restrict representations to subgroups (or induce from). Usually the group and subgroup are geometrically or combinatorially defined (for example, $S_{n-1}\leq S_n$ or $\mathrm{GL}_{n-1}(q)\leq \mathrm{GL}_n(q)$), and the rule is usually combinatorial in nature. For both of the examples I gave, the ordinary characters and unipotent characters respectively are labelled by partitions, and restriction and Harish-Chandra restriction respectively are given by removing a (removable) box from the partition.

Comment: Does one concept contain the other? +1 thanks! <3

Comment: Not really, although they are related. Branching rules need not be complete. For example, the branching rule for symmetric groups from $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$ is perfect for characteristic $0$, but for characteristic $p$ it is far from understood, despite a lot of work by Kleshchev. If you obtain a decomposition of a module, then it is generally perfect, not a general description. And it often applies to a particular situation only.. A decomposition of the tensor square of a module might be valid only for some types of groups. And you only ever talk about branching when doing restriction/induction.